# tic tac toe javascript answer checker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am making a simple tic tac toe game in javascript/jquery and i have no idea how i can check if someone won.
this is the gamefield:

```
<div id="gamefield">
            <table border="0">
                <tr>
                    <td><img alt="" title="" src="img/empty.jpg" /></td>
                    <td><img alt="" title="" src="img/empty.jpg" /></td>
                    <td><img alt="" title="" src="img/empty.jpg" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><img alt="" title="" src="img/empty.jpg" /></td>
                    <td><img alt="" title="" src="img/empty.jpg" /></td>
                    <td><img alt="" title="" src="img/empty.jpg" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><img alt="" title="" src="img/empty.jpg" /></td>
                    <td><img alt="" title="" src="img/empty.jpg" /></td>
                    <td><img alt="" title="" src="img/empty.jpg" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
```

this is the code that changes the empty.jpg into cross.jpg or circle.jpg:

```
$("#gamefieldtr td").click( function (event) {
if($(".game-button").html() == "Reset game" && $(this).children().attr("src") == "img/empty.jpg") {

    if(randomStart == 0){
        var val = $(this).children().attr('src', 'img/cross.jpg');
        randomStart = 1;
        $(this).children().unbind("click");
    }
    else {
        var val = $(this).children().attr('src', 'img/circle.jpg');
        randomStart = 0;
        $(this).children().unbind("click");
    }
}
if ($(".game-button").html() == "Start game") {
    alert("you can't start");
}
});
```

and this is the randomstart code:

```
var randomStart = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
```

Comment: You can keep your model on a 3,3 size matrix and check if row or column or diagonals are ok to win

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [React tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/react/tutorial/tutorial.html) implements a TicTacToe game and they use this function to check who won:

```
function calculateWinner(squares) {
  const lines = [
    [0, 1, 2],
    [3, 4, 5],
    [6, 7, 8],
    [0, 3, 6],
    [1, 4, 7],
    [2, 5, 8],
    [0, 4, 8],
    [2, 4, 6],
  ];
  for (let i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    const [a, b, c] = lines[i];
    if (squares[a] && squares[a] === squares[b] && squares[a] === squares[c]) {
      return squares[a];
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

from the [starter source code](https://codepen.io/ericnakagawa/pen/vXpjwZ?editors=0010)

Squares is an array of the nine squares from left to right, top to bottom. It contains `x` or `o` for already filled in squares and returns the letter of the winner.